# In Responsive Web Design, how can I use Javascript or jQuery to stop a function and reset when the users downsizes their window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design

I have a responsive layout and I've created a fading panels animated element with jQuery. I set the jQuery function to only activate if the user is above a certain screen size. However, if I scale the window down, the function still runs.

Here's what I'd like to achieve:

1. When the user scrolls bellow a browser width of 1440px, stop that fading panels animation.
2. Once the animation is stopped, I want to reset the area to display the 1st panel.
3. If the user scrolls back up above that screen size, start the animation again.

Here is my code, thanks in advance for your time:

```
// Get the viewport size!
var viewport = $(document).width();

if (viewport >= 1140) {

var InfiniteRotator = 
{
    init: function() 
    {
        // hard set height of container
        $('#circles').height('286.717px');

        // initial fade-in time
        var initialInterval = 3000;

        // interval between items
        var itemInterval = 5000;

        // cross-fade time
        var fadeTime = 2000;

        // count number of items
        var numberOfItem = $('.rotating-item').length;

        // set current item
        var currentItem = 0;

        // create loop
        var infiniteLoop = setInterval(function() { 

            // initial fade out
            $('.rotating-item').eq(currentItem).fadeOut(fadeTime);

            // set counter
            if (currentItem == numberOfItem -1) {
                currentItem = 0;
            } else {
                currentItem++;
            }

            // next item fade in
            $('.rotating-item').eq(currentItem).fadeIn(fadeTime);

        }, itemInterval);
    }
}

// go Go GO!
InfiniteRotator.init();
}
```

Please note: I used this great tutorial to create the fading panels: http://trendmedia.com/news/infinite-rotating-images-using-jquery-javascript/

Comment: Do you have any live view? JSFiddle?

Comment: Sure here's the live site: http://owenevans.net/ ... the fading panels is on the right, where the three circles are. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
window.onresize = function() {
    clearInterval(infiniteLoop)
}
```

Note that you must still be in your `init` function in order to get the `infiniteLoop` variable.

Comment: Fantastic! This stops the function on resize, is it possible to start the function again if the window goes about 1140px wide again? Thanks

Comment: This a resize event (see answers below). The best way is to break your plugin in two main methods : create and destrok, and to bind these event to a resize in your init method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
window.onresize = function(){ ... }
```

Comment: Thank you, but how do I stop the function that I started earlier?

Comment: You may pass the window size to the function and then set two different behavours inside the function with a switch or if statement.

Comment: Also, the syntax in my answer is pure js while the user ocanal (see his answer) gave you the jquery statement, if you are already using this library you can opt for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  //stop and reset animation in here.
});
```

Comment: How do you stop the animation?